# JodaTime LocalDate JSON deserialization ISO 8601 issue

Tags: android, json, serialization, jodatime, iso8601

I have a `LocalDate` that is serialized into `JSON` to be: `"2014-10-17"`. When I attempt to parse it with the code mentioned below I get a logcat error that the format is incorrect.

Here is the logcat:

```
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanospark.cnc/com.nanospark.cnc.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: ""2014-10-17""
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: ""2014-10-17""
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:854)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:798)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.nanospark.cnc.LocalDateSerializer.deserialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:37)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.nanospark.cnc.LocalDateSerializer.deserialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:1)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.nanospark.cnc.GlobalData.retrieveGlobalDataFromStorage(GlobalData.java:115)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at com.nanospark.cnc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-16 22:55:30.123: E/AndroidRuntime(31319):    ... 11 more
```

As well as the class that handles serialization and deserialization:

```
public class LocalDateSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>, JsonSerializer<LocalDate>
{
   private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.date();

   @Override
   public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonElement je, final Type type,
                           final JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
   {
      final String dateAsString = je.getAsString();
      Log.v("My Date Deserialized", je.getAsString());
      if (je.isJsonNull() || dateAsString.length()==0)
      {
         return null;
      }
      else
      {
         return DATE_FORMAT.parseLocalDate(dateAsString);         
      }
   }

   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(final LocalDate src, final Type typeOfSrc,
                                final JsonSerializationContext context)
   {
      String retVal;
      if (src == null)
      {
         retVal = "";
      }
      else
      {
         retVal = DATE_FORMAT.print(src);
      }
      Log.v("My Date Serialized", retVal);
      return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);
   }
}
```

Is `yyyy-MM-dd` not considered ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Does `dateAsString` contain quotation marks? The error message seems to indicate that.

Comment: Let me test that out.

Comment: Yes that appears to be the issue; is there a way to remove the quotation marks? otherwise I just substituted the `parseLocalDate(dateAsString)` for `parseLocalDate(je.getAsString())`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by quotation marks being added around my `dateAsString` value.

Just simply substituting `parseLocalDate(dateAsString)` with `parseLocalDate(je.getAsString())` fixed the issue.